# Can anyone pls troubleshoot this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I know probably there is a silly mistake in my circuit, but I can't seem to find it !

The circuit is a non inverting amplifier supposed to amplify the input signal (which has a range of 0 to 5V) with a gain of 2. The circuit needs to work off of a single supply of 12V. Is the schematic correct for these specifications ?

Also will the circuit output 0V when the input voltage is 0V(or will the voltage be the lower saturtion voltage of the IC)?. By the way, I have to use this IC, hence I cannot use a rail to rail op-amp.

[image: My circuit]

Comment: What is the range of the input signal?

Comment: @PhilG the input range is from 0 to 5V

Comment: Is pin 4 a negative 12 volts?

Comment: @rdtsc no pin 4 is positive 12v.

Comment: You need the connection dot between the op-amp output and R1.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thats not an issue, I am asking if the circuit design itself is correct pls

Comment: No, it’s not correct- without the dot it won’t simulate correctly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I know. It still doesn't work like I want it when I make a proper connection

Comment: The circuit (with the connection) should work fine, there's nothing wrong with it. "doesn't work like I want it" is a bit vague. Do you mean there's 3mV of error near 0V or do you mean it's outputting 1kV when it should be 2V?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany for some reason it works properly from 200mV to 5V but for less than 200mV, the output is 11.47V ? Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: 'doesn't work' is not a symptom, tell us what it **does** do. Is it the case that you haven't actually biuilt this thing, but are looking at a simulation? If so, what simulator, what model of the 324? You can in general assume nothing about what a model does if you didn't write it yourself.

Comment: @Neil_UK you got me, I was only trying out in simulation and it was driving me crazy ! Then I tried it on a breadboard and the circuit works as expected. I appreciate your help !

Comment: it should work in simulation if you connect R1 to the output. Some simulation models are *ideal* in that they ignore powers supply issues. If they include maximum output swings and input common mode range, some make it work like a *typical* device in the datasheet, some make it work like the worst edge case in the datasheet, and have either realistic or undefined behaviour outside the in specification range. 'My circuit doesn't work' questions are usually a proto-board that has been assembled incorrectly, a wire has become detatached, shorted to another component, in the wrong hole etc.

Comment: many amplifiers invert their output signal, in real life, if one of the inputs goes outside the input voltage common mode range. I don't know whether 324 is one of these. However, the specification is for common mode to include ground, so behaving badly at 200mV seems to be wrong for any model. 324 has plenty of manufacturers, get some models from other sources, drop them into the simulator, and compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from a missing connection dot between the amplifier output and R1, it seems reasonable.

The 10k feedback values are plenty low enough to drive the input bias current, and plenty high enough to be driven by the amplifier.

The input voltage common mode range includes ground on the LM324, and the output will get near to ground, even if it won't sink much current when the output voltage is 10s of mV. If the load is connected to ground, then it should pull the output all the way down to ground for zero input.

With a gain of 2, you will saturate the amplifier output before you reach the upper limit of the input voltage range.

12v is a reasonable power supply voltage. The amplifier has specifications at 5v , and a max supply IIRC of 32v. I usually get the quad amplifier power and ground the wrong way round, they are on the wrong sides for me. You have drawn the schematic correctly, have you wired it up correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that pin4 is supply and pin 11 is ground. So what do you suggest to change about my circuit ? Should I replace the ground connection on R2 with a 5V source to shift the op-amp ?

Comment: @SamwelPortelli The schematic is OK. How is the circuit built? PCB, perf board, stripboard, plugin proto board, air-wired rat's nest? I'd be inclined to connect the amps as followers, and see if they follow. Or maybe pull it apart and rebuild, but in a different order so you're less likely to make the same wiring mistake again. You might have a broken IC?

Comment: The circuit has not yet been tested in real life, it has just been tested in the simulator

Comment: Texas Instrument suggest adding a common mode voltage of half the supply voltage when to the non inverting pin of the op-amp? Do you know why ?

Comment: The bias voltage into the inverting pin defines the pivot point of the input and output signals (more or less) if your input and output are ground referenced then your feedback network is good.  you might not get a full 10V out for 5V in but that's a limitation of the 324 not a problem with your circuit layout. (assuming the missing dot is placed) going to a higher supply voltage (eg 15V) should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you mention the **actual** improper operation you observed in simulation:

> @SpehroPefhany for some reason it works properly from 200mV to 5V but for less than 200mV, the output is 11.47V ? Do you have any idea why ? – Samwel Portelli 2 hours ago

This, I **can** answer, however the simulation model in Circuitlab is insufficiently true to the actual behavior of the LM358 to show it, so I go to LTspice.

The problem is real- it exists in real life as well as simulation and has tripped up many a neophyte designer.

When you apply a voltage to the non-inverting input of the LM358 that is more than a few hundred mV below ground (the negative supply), the output will swing up to close to the positive rail. This is called "phase reversal", and a number of op-amps suffer from this behavior.

Below is the circuit with a 1V peak (centered on 0V) sine wave applied to the non-inverting input. If you try this in real life, insert a small resistor in series  with the signal input to limit the current. I'm not worried about burning out the simulated op-amp.

[image]

To the left,  you can see the expected behavior- the input signal looks like half a sine wave and is amplified x2. To the right, you see that the output shoots up to near the positive rail during the negative half cycle.